# Show that $\int_{0}^{1}P(x)f(x)=0$

Tags: functions, polynomials

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function, such that $\exists (u,v)\in [0,1]$; $ f(u)>0, f(v)<0$.

Show that there exists $P$ a polynomial such that $P>0$ over $[0,1]$ and

$\int_{0}^{1}P(x)f(x)=0$

Comment: How about considering $P(x)=\alpha(x-u)^2+\beta(x-v)^2$, with $\alpha,\beta>0$, and using continuity of $(\alpha,\beta)\to\int P(x)f(x)$ ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it

Comment: It was just an idea, which I don't think actually works. See MotylaNogaTomkaMazu's answer for a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists two polynomials $P,Q\in\mathbb{R} [x]$ such that $P(x) >0 , Q(x)>0$ for $x\in [0,1] $ and $$\int_{[0,1]} P(x) f(x)dx =\alpha >0 \wedge \int_{[0,1]} Q(x) f(x)dx =-\beta <0$$ hence if we take $W(x) =\alpha^{-1} P(x) +\beta^{-1} Q(x) $ we get $W(x) >0 $ for $x\in [0,1] $ and $$ \int_{[0,1]} W(x) f(x)dx =0.$$

Comment: First, it's not clear why such $P$ and $Q$ exist. Second, it's not clear why $W>0$.

Comment: @AlexM. I am guessing the existence of $P$ can be shown using the density of polynomials in $\mathcal C([0,1])$, approximating a function $g\geq\epsilon>0$ that has a spike on a neighbourhood of $u$ where $f>0$. Same goes for $Q$. Given such $P$ and $Q$, the positivity of $W$ is automatic, is it not?

Comment: @AlexM. I think you misread, $\beta$ is actually $>0$. Since both $P$ and $Q$ are $>0$, $W$ is the sum of two positives functions.